What are the usage limits & costs for the Google People API?
I am working on a chrome extension that I would like to offer to around 500 people for free using the Google People API.
Does anyone know the usage costs for the Google People API? I am trying to figure out if this free model approach is feasible.

Does this answer your question? people API google quota limits

fyi this is off-topic, as there's no programming question. This is a pricing+documentation question. It's also arguably a customer service question, which is off-topic - see Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?

There is no cost in regard the use of the API's only if you require more quota than the current limits (previous acceptance and agreement) and these may or may not be documented, but still can be found in your GCP project
API increase and possible charges

API & Services > QUotas and limits

The quota will be consumed per user per request and depends on the method
https://developers.google.com/people/v1/contacts
after the user exahust the quota or if a timeframe perlimit is breached the API will show 429/500 errors, exponential back off algorithm will help you prevent the time errors
if a per day quota is consumed the user will need to wait 24 hours to use the API again
I hope you find this information useful

Please don't answer customer service questions. The question itself is not a programming question and is off-topic.
